# Convert Link to 'a href' link in multi data Csv file in Open refine

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, openrefine

I am a beginner in OpenRefine and GREL and I want to transform the links of my CSV file (which contains 500 records) into clickable HTML links with a `href = ""`.

For example:
`http://www.my-link.com` becomes `<a href="http://www.my-link.com"> http://www.my-link.com </a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate in GREL by simply using  the `+` sign. For your example the expression is: `'<a href="'+value+'">'+value+'</a>'`

You need to put any hard coded string between single quote `'` so OpenRefine is not confused with the actual double-quote `"` of the HTML.

Comment: If the solution provided work for you, can you accept the answer in SO? thank you

Comment: Thank you, but i dont know how to accept answer in SO..?

Comment: See this tutorial for accepting answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ah ! thank'u, at the beginning I tried with the up and down arrows, but I was not allowed to evaluate my own answer, have a nice day !